# Extract values from 2 php multidimensional arrays at same time looping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am with **2 string arrays**, in one I have the full *size image url*, other have *thumbnail image url*.

I am bulding a `<img>` tag with a `for loop`, but I dont know how to access to second array values from it. I try make an example with this:

```
$array_images[70] = array("image1", "image2", "image3");        
$array_thumbs[70] = array("thumb1", "thumb2", "thumb3");        

print_r($array_images);
print_r($array_thumbs);


foreach( $array_images as $key => $value ){
    foreach( $value as $keyv => $valuev ){
        echo $valuev."\n";
    }
}
```

This the output:

```
Array
(
    [70] => Array
        (
            [0] => image1
            [1] => image2
            [2] => image3
        )

)
Array
(
    [70] => Array
        (
            [0] => thumb1
            [1] => thumb2
            [2] => thumb3
        )

)
image1
image2
image3
```

I want show image1->thumb1. But I dont know how merge two arrays in for loops, really tried with some loops but I dont solve it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: If both arrays have the same indexes `foreach( $array_images as $key => $value ){
    foreach( $value as $keyv => $valuev ){
        echo $valuev. "  " . $array_thumbs[$key][$keyv] . "\n";
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code 'joins' the 2 arrays together:

```
$array = array();
array_walk(array_combine($images, $thumbs), function($v, $k) use(&$array){
    $array[] = array(
        'image' => $k,
        'thumb' => $v
    );
});
```

---

`print_r($array);` will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => image1
            [thumb] => thumb1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image] => image2
            [thumb] => thumb2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image] => image3
            [thumb] => thumb3
        )

)
```

Note that I used variables called `images` and `thumbs` instead. See the code in action [here](https://eval.in/606350).

---

And if you want to loop the new array, use something like this:

```
foreach($array as $v){
    echo 'Thumb: ' . $v['thumb'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Image: ' . $v['image'] . '<br><br>';
}
```

The output:

```
Thumb: thumb1
Image: image1

Thumb: thumb2
Image: image2

Thumb: thumb3
Image: image3
```

See it in action [here](https://eval.in/606352).

Answer (score 1):

Since both Arrays are equal in length and use numeric indices (with the value of each index for one of the Arrays corresponding to the that of the other: **Parallel Arrays**) you could safely use only one loop for both... and then use the `$key` to access the other. The Snippet below would suffice to illustrate the idea...

```
    <?php
        // SIMULATING SUB-ARRAYS FOR FULL-SIZE IMAGES...
        $array_images1      = array("image1", "image2", "image3");
        $array_images2      = array("image4", "image5", "image6");

        // SIMULATING SUB-ARRAYS FOR THUMBNAIL IMAGES...
        $array_thumbs1      = array("thumb1", "thumb2", "thumb3");
        $array_thumbs2      = array("thumb4", "thumb5", "thumb6");

        // SIMULATING MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY OF FULL/THUMB IMAGES...
        $array_main_full    = array($array_images1, $array_images2);  //<== SAME KEY/SAME IMAGE ONLY FULL.
        $array_thumbs_full  = array($array_thumbs1, $array_thumbs2);;  //<== SAME KEY/SAME IMAGE ONLY THUMB.

        // ONE LOOP: INTENDED RESULT
        foreach($array_main_full as $iKey=>$array_images){
            foreach( $array_images as $key => $value ){
                echo $value . "<br />";
                echo $array_thumbs_full[$iKey][$key] . "<br /><br />";
            }

        }

        // PRODUCES::           
        string 'image1' (length=6)
        string 'thumb1' (length=6)

        string 'image2' (length=6)
        string 'thumb2' (length=6)

        string 'image3' (length=6)
        string 'thumb3' (length=6)

        string 'image4' (length=6)
        string 'thumb4' (length=6)

        string 'image5' (length=6)
        string 'thumb5' (length=6)

        string 'image6' (length=6)
        string 'thumb6' (length=6)
```

Confirm it [HERE](https://eval.in/606351).

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_combine

```
$images = array_combine($array_images,$array_thumbs);
```